# How Can You Drag and Drop Inside Custom Shapes (JavaScript, jQuery UI or Interact JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I Try To Drag from List And Drop inside crosses circles the same image below:

[image]

But when I touch the div it's can drop outside the circle, I try with CSS (Border Radius, Overflow, Clip Path) but nothing works.

[image]

You Can See in this Image The List Dropped outside the Circle but inside div.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As you have not provided a Minimal, Reproducible Example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ), I will have to make a lot of assumptions.jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable are based on the Box model, so it will always start at that point. For droppable, you can use a Function with `accept`: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept *"A function that will be called for each draggable on the page (passed as the first argument to the function). The function must return true if the draggable should be accepted."*

Comment: See More: http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/point-circle.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need Collision Detection. You will need to determine if a Point is inside the Circle.

An example of this can be seen here: http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/point-circle.php

> Why do we need this? We can use the Pythagorean Theorem to get the distance between two objects in 2D space! In this context, `a` and `b` are the horizontal and vertical distances between the point and the center of the circle.

I used the Demo here: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ I created this example.

```js
$(function() {
  function getCenter(el) {
    return {
      x: $(el).position().left + ($(el).width() / 2),
      y: $(el).position().top + ($(el).height() / 2)
    }
  }

  function getPoints(el) {
    return [{
      x: $(el).position().left,
      y: $(el).position().top
    }, {
      x: $(el).position().left + $(el).width(),
      y: $(el).position().top
    }, {
      x: $(el).position().left,
      y: $(el).position().top + $(el).height()
    }, {
      x: $(el).position().left + $(el).width(),
      y: $(el).position().top + $(el).height()
    }];
  }

  function pointInsideCircle(pObj, cObj) {
    var distX = pObj.x - cObj.x;
    var distY = pObj.y - cObj.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((distX * distX) + (distY * distY));
    if (distance <= cObj.r) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  $("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: function(el) {
      var points = getPoints(el);
      var circ = getCenter(this);
      circ['r'] = $(this).width() / 2;
      return pointInsideCircle(points[0], circ);
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0.2em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#droppable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

In this example, it is using the Top Left point of the Drag element for detection only. You can test each corner, and if any are inside, return true. This would be similar to a `touch` type of detection.

If the Top Left corner is not inside the circle, Drop will not accept it.

Comment: Thank You, It's Work
I Try to know whats circle point is inside, how can id do that?

Comment: @RamyMoustafa I am not sure what you mean. Please try making it work on your own. If you get stuck further, you can search for another answer or post another question.